# How to (re-)follow a post on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Normally, after I comment on a friend's post on Facebook, I'll receive notifications whenever someone else also comments on the same post. But after about five follow-up comments or so, I stop getting notifications. Is there a way to re-follow a post in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has standardised this with a feature called **Get Notifications**, which is accessible from the arrow menu in the top right corner of a post. To get notifications from a post on a friends wall, open the detail page of the wall post by clicking on the post timestamp (i.e. 2hrs) and repeat the same procedure with Get Notifications again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you'd like to re-follow a post, in your Newsfeed you should be able to click the arrow at the top-right and select *Follow Post*

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that definitely helps. However, not all posts appear in the news feed. For example, a post made by a friend of a friend on said friend's wall will not show up. How would I (re-)follow *those* posts?

Comment: I wonder if that's because of the 3rd person's privacy settings, but I could be wrong. In any case, you could try going to your friend's timeline and click on `Friends > Settings > All Updates`